# Python format percentages

Tags: python, formatting, percentage

I use the following snippet for converting a ratio into a percentage:

`"{:2.1f}%".format(value * 100)`

This works as you would expect. I want to extend this to be more informative in edge cases, where the rounded ratio is 0 or 1, but not exactly.

Is there a more pythonic way, perhaps using the `format` function, to do this? Alternatively I would add a clause similar to:

```
if math.isclose(value, 0) and value != 0:
    return "< 0.1"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend running `round` to figure out if the string formatting is going to round the ratio to 0 or 1. This function also has the option to choose how many decimal places to round to:

```
def get_rounded(value, decimal=1):
    percent = value*100
    almost_one = (round(percent, decimal) == 100) and percent < 100
    almost_zero = (round(percent, decimal) == 0) and percent > 0
    if almost_one:
        return "< 100.0%"
    elif almost_zero:
        return "> 0.0%"
    else:
        return "{:2.{decimal}f}%".format(percent, decimal=decimal)

for val in [0, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.5, 0.999, 0.9999, 1]:
    print(get_rounded(val, 1))
```

Which outputs:

```
0.0%
> 0.0%
0.1%
50.0%
99.9%
< 100.0%
100.0%
```

I don't believe there is a shorter way to do it. I also wouldn't recommend using `math.isclose`, as you'd have to use `abs_tol` and it wouldn't be as readable.

Comment: Thanks. Knitpicking for future reference: shouldn't it be `> 99.9%` instead of `< 100.0%`?

Comment: I suppose that would be more useful information to convey. Edit it as you see fit, you could also make that vary based on the decimal value as well.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming Python 3.6+, marking exactly zero or exactly 100% could be done with:

```
>>> for value in (0.0,0.0001,.9999,1.0):
...   f"{value:6.1%}{'*' if value == 0.0 or value == 1.0 else ' '}"
...
'  0.0%*'
'  0.0% '
'100.0% '
'100.0%*'
```